# How do I wrap standard C file functions (i.e., close, stat, etc.) using --wrap?

Tags: c, gcc, gdb, static-libraries

I am trying to understand why I am unable to use successfully wrap the functions open(), close(), stat() and fstat(). I have successfully wrapped several network functions (socket(), bind(), accept(), send(), recv(), etc.) and even a misc. function (select()).

To include these files, I create a static library containing all my wrap functions and add the following options to my autotools configure script:

```
LDFLAGS="-Wl,--wrap=socket,--wrap=bind,--wrap=accept,--wrap=send,--wrap=recv,--wrap=select,--wrap=open,--wrap=close,--wrap=stat,--wrap=fstat -static-libgcc -L/path/to/my/wrap/library
LIBS="-lwrap"
```

When I debug in GDB this is the result for fstat() for example:

```
(gdb) 0x000000000041aea4     40     if (-1 == fstat(fd, &st)) {
(gdb) 0x00000000004f45c0 in fstat64 ()
(gdb) 0x00000000004f4620 in _fxstat ()
```

However, for send() I get the following result:

```
(gdb) 0x000000000040c55f     107     return send(fd, data, len, 0);
(gdb) 0x0000000000476cca in __wrap_send ()
```

Here are my close and fstat wrap functions:

```
int __wrap_close(int fd) {
    // pretend this always succeeds
    return 0;
}

int __wrap_fstat(int fd, struct stat *statbuf)
{
    // pretend this always succeeds
    return 0;
}
```

Edit: As requested, here are some more details:

Configure script:

```
CFLAGS="-g --static" 
LDFLAGS="-Wl,--wrap=socket -Wl,--wrap=bind -Wl,--wrap=accept -Wl,--wrap=send -Wl,--wrap=recv -Wl,--wrap=select -Wl,--wrap=close -Wl,--wrap=stat -Wl,--wrap=fstat -static-libgcc -L/path/to/static/wrap/library" 
LIBS="-lwrap" 
LIGHTTPD_STATIC=yes ./configure --prefix=/path/to/lighttpd/install --enable-static --disable-shared --without-zlib --disable-ipv6 --without-bzip2 --without-pcre
```

Then I execute using the following:

```
./install/sbin/lighttpd -D -f lighttpd.conf
```

Note, the default lighttpd.conf given on their website can be used to reproduce this issue.

Comment: I've never used this before but just tried with `fstat` and `close` and that worked fine.

Comment: Interesting. I compiled my executable completely statically, but even with a dynamic executable I still have the same result. Did you set your LDFLAGS and LIB the exact same way as I did for each of those functions?

Comment: It is well possible, that this call is in the same translation unit as the implementation of `fstat()`, and so the compiler decided to resolve the call immediately. (However, the addresses seem to indicate that this is not true.) -- Another possibility is that `fstat()` is a macro, using `fstat64()` as the real function, as GDB's output suggests. Did you check this? Did you try to wrap `fstat64()`? -- Would you mind to provide a [example], please? The command lines to compile and link would be helpful, too.

Comment: I just created an object file with the wrapper functions (with the same flags you have in LDFLAGS) and then linked with that object file using the same flags when compiling the final program

Comment: Do you succeed if you just create a small app yourself, not involving autotools etc.?

Comment: Update: I found that fstat64() while resolving some, did not resolve all references to fstat. This is due to the gmtime() function in lighttpd which invokes several different functions including fstat under the hood. Unfortunately, even with __wrap_fstat and __wrap_fstat64 I am unable to mock the fstat used underneath gmtime() (which is only referenced as _fxstat() in gdb).